# Why isn't while(getline(...)) executing multiple times against stringstreams?

Tags: c++

I am using a while(getline(...)) structure to break a stringstream filled with many tab characters into individual chunks for data processing. The while loop that actually does the breaking operates correctly for the first line, but then does not enter execution for any of the other lines in the dataset, even when updating the stringstream using str().

I am currently working on parsing a dataset. Because the dataset contains many commas, and because I know std::getline() has an argument to work with unique delimiters, I chose to export the dataset as a .tsv instead of the usual .csv. My logic for taking a line and splitting it up into each cell followed how I almost always do it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        getline(inputfile, tsvLine);
        lineStream.str(tsvLine);
        while(getline(lineStream, currentChunk, '\t')){
            cout << "[Part: " << ++counter << "] "; 
            cout << currentChunk << endl;
        }
    }
```

Everything inside the for loop is my code for breaking a line of a .tsv up. Take *inputfile* (a ifstream) and getline it into *tsvLine* (a string), use that string to update the stringstream *lineStream*. Once *lineStream* is updated, throw it in a while(getline()) delimited by the tab character to break each part into a *currentChunk* (a string) and print it out. This works for the first line in the .tsv, and correctly counts 65 chunks.

The for loop at the top was put in place just as a placeholder so I could run the code on the first four lines of the file. However, the next three lines do not run. Debugging shows that tsvLine is correctly updated, and so is lineStream (I have done `cout << lineStream.str();` to verify this,) but the while loop simply does not enter the second time around and I am very unsure why.

I have looked into `lineStream.ignore();`, just calling getline() again to make sure the buffer is clear, manually clearing it with `lineStream.str("");`, and I have even tested the code out on different first lines to make sure it always reads one line successfully (it does,) but no matter what I do, I just cannot seem to get that while loop to enter a second time. A lot of other questions surrounding this topic seem to mention being careful around `cin >>` and the newline character `\n`, which I deliberately try using getline() to avoid. I am at a loss.

Comment: Unrelated: `getline(inputfile, tsvLine);` has no checks to ensure the read succeeded and there is a valid input in `tsvLine`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you replace the underlying string, it does not clear the stream state. After you process your first line of data, your stream will be in an error state which must be cleared. Because you're not doing this, all subsequent use of the stream will fail.

You should be able to fix this problem by adding a call to `.clear()`:

```
lineStream.str(tsvLine);
lineStream.clear();
```

This isn't a very C++ way to do it though. Generally, you would define the object inside the loop and use RAII instead:

```
std::istringStream lineStream(tsvLine);
```

This gives you a fresh object, and you don't need to worry about dirty state from previous use.

Side-note: in your for-loop you are not actually checking if the line was successfully read from `inputfile`. Failure to do this might cause additional problems.

Comment: Thank you! This is all really good info. The `getline(inputfile, tsvLine);` was moved into a while loop to replace the for loop to make sure things worked in the final build, that was only temporary.